# "At times" or "at the same time"

Tags: difference, meaning

> A deeply conservative pontiff, whose tenure has been overshadowed by sexual abuse scandals, Pope Benedict, 85, leaves with a chequered reputation after a papacy that was **at times** both conservative and divisive.
>
> [(The Guardian)](http://m.guardian.co.uk/world/2013/feb/11/pope-benedict-xvi-resigns-age)

Yes, this is a basic question, but I'm wondering why the journalist uses "at times" rather than "at the same time." Are these expressions identical in meaning?

Comment: Because he means that sometimes, but not *all* the time, it was both conservative and divisive. We tend to use "at the same time" when we feel that two qualities *contrast* in some important respect: *at the same time conservative and radical*.

Comment: I think, in the context, they do contrast.  Radical is synonymous with divisive to the stuffy bunch that are the upper levels of the Catholic Church

Answer (score 5):

The use of *at the same time* would make the phrase refer to the papacy as a whole.  That is, it would indicate that the entirety of Benedict's papacy was both conservative and divisive; every single action that he undertook could be considered that way.

The use of *at times*, on the other hand, is a much weaker statement, claiming only that there were occasional actions undertaken by the Pope that were both conservative and divisive.  So while there may have been controversy once in a while, it was not a "constant feature" of the pope's entire reign, but rather "just enough" to leave him with a "chequered reputation."

Comment: OP seems to take *at the same time* to refer to *conservative and divisive*. *At the same time*, in the sense you propose, seems impossible; the 'time' can't be the *same* as the entire course of his papacy, because that is not previously mentioned.

Comment: I'm breaking it down as either: the papacy was both conservative and divisive (and we are explicitly mentioning that it was both of these at the same time), or there were times at which the papacy was both conservative and divisive (and there were other times at which it was neither).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes his decisions were conservative: he clamped down on moves to consider the ordination of female clergy; sometimes they were divisive: he preached the evils of rampant capitalism (on a par with terrorism) when the Church's traditional position has favoured capitalisam and especially over the 'evils' of communism.

So, at times it was conservative, at times it was divisive (or, *at times, both conservative and divisive*).

Info on decisions found here:  http://www.newrepublic.com/article/112389/pope-benedict-resigns-what-his-legacy-america#